# How to format the number of digits for categorical variables in 'gtsummary::tbl_summary'?

Tags: r, digits, gtsummary

I am unable to figure out how to tell the tbl_summary function to display decimal places when summarizing categorical variables. It works quite well with continuous variables like 'mpg', but not for 'cyl'.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

# with decimal places
mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg) %>% 
  tbl_summary(digits = list(everything() ~ c(2)))

# no decimal places
mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl) %>% 
  tbl_summary(digits = list(everything() ~ c(2)))
```

Thanks!

Richi

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To update the number of digits the percentages are rounded to use the `digits=` argument. In the example below, pass `c(0, 2)`. The zero indicates to round the N to the nearest integer, and the 2 indicates to round the percentage to 2 decimal places.

Happy Coding!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.0'

# with decimal places
tbl <-
  mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl) %>% 
  tbl_summary(digits = list(all_categorical() ~ c(0, 2)))
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Does `style_percent()` works within the digits argument of the tbl_summary function?

Comment: @RockinRichi if you like the answer provided, you can click the green check mark to indicate the question was answered :)

Comment: Looking forward to future features for this great package!

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Thanks. Upvoted. Any thoughts on how to report 1 decimal for continuous variables if I am reporting both continuous and categorical variables simultaneously?